# How do I get my Gmail friends online status

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, gmail

I am developing one web application using (PHP JavaScript). 
I stuck to one point that I wanted to get my Gmail friend(s) online status.

e.g. I would provide one of my Gmail friend IDs i.e. abc@gmail.com as input to the API (if such an API is exist) and ultimately I wanted to track whether he is online or offline through normal script (PHP/JavaScript/jQuery/other).

Please folks provide me your necessary pointer(s) in this case. Does such API/library exist in PHP, Java script, jQuery or any other? How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is xmpphp, may be can help
http://code.google.com/p/xmpphp/

Use this module with some code like:

```
<?php
include("xmpp.php");
$conn = new XMPP('talk.google.com', 5222, 'user', 'password', 'xmpphp', 'gmail.com', $printlog=True, $loglevel=LOGGING_INFO);
$conn->connect();
while(!$conn->disconnected) {
    $payloads = $conn->processUntil(array('presence'));
    foreach($payloads as $event) {
        $pl = $event[1];
        print "Presence: {$pl['from']} [{$pl['show']}] {$pl['status']}\n";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: This is usefull for a simple bot allthough this will get scaling issues when you have a lot of users. Also I would like to know how he could hook this up to an API? I don't think it is possible

Comment: @Alfred: Just an sample, but basically it can get the users state list. it must be modified to use for specific case (with asynchronize, periodical, maintain info in session level..how wisely you get and reuse status data).

Answer (score 0):

You could use Google app engine's [XMPP service](http://code.google.com/intl/nl-NL/appengine/docs/python/xmpp/overview.html)(automagically scales) for this(It has a generous free quota). There is also a java SDK but coding in python would be way shorter. The api has a `get_presence(jid, from_jid=None)` function which

`Returns True if the user is online and available, False if the user is not online or away.`

You could just hook it up to http(webhook) to create a simple api. If you watch the video [Developing and deploying an application on Google App Engine](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bfgO-LXGpTM), you will learn how to develop a simple app and to deploy it to google app engine.

I think you can create this XMPP api in about 25 minutes(10 minutes to watch the video) and have learned a little bit about the fun to use language python.